# What assert do in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I just want to know what's the use of **assert** in a Dart. I was tried to figure it out by myself but I'm not able to do that. It would be great if someone explains to me the use of **assert**.

Comment: Have you read https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert ?  As with other programming languages, `assert` is used to validate your assumptions in debug builds without affecting release builds.

Comment: Just to complement in case someone else is in doubt, to run the dart and see a message error in case assert returns false, try running `dart run name_of_program.dart --enable-asserts`

Comment: It must be noted that if you want to use `assert` then you have to enable it while execution as it can only be used in the development mode and not in productive mode. If it is not enabled then it will be simply be ignored while execution.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Main purpose of `assert` is testing conditions during debugging/development.

Let's think about this example:

```dart
class Product {
  Product({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.price,
    this.size,
    this.image,
    this.weight,
  })  : assert(id > 0),
        assert(name.isNotEmpty),
        assert(price > 0.0);

  final int id;
  final String name;
  final double price;
  final String? size;
  final String? image;
  final int? weight;
}
```

We have a `Product` class and fields like `id`, `name` and `price` are mandatory, but other fields can be handled by generic values, as you guess. By asserting required fields, you'll test this data class during debugging/development. Keep in the mind, all asserts are ignored in release/production mode;

From the [dart.dev#assert](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert):

> In production code, assertions are ignored, and the arguments to assert aren’t evaluated.

Comparing to writing tests, even though they are not the same thing, asserts can be very handy with minimal effort, so be generous for writing asserts, especially if you don't write tests, it always rewards you.

Since constants like `kDebugMode`, `kReleaseMode` are part of `package:flutter/foundation.dart`, another use case is `debugMode` specific codes in `Non-Flutter` applications. Let's have a look at this code:

```dart
bool get isDebugMode {
  bool value = false;
  assert(() {
    value = true;
    //you can execute debug-specific codes here
    return true;
  }());
  return value;
}
```

At first it may look confusing, it's a tricky yet simple code. An anonymous closure always returns true, so we don't throw any exception in any case. Since the compiler eliminates the assert statements in release mode, that closure only runs in debug mode and mutates the `value` variable.

When debugging, you can also extend the use cases like this example, from `Flutter` source code:

```dart
void addAll(Iterable<E> iterable) {
  int i = this.length;
  for (E element in iterable) {
    assert(this.length == i || (throw ConcurrentModificationError(this)));
    add(element);
    i++;
  }
}
```

Again, exception is only thrown in debug mode and you can now distinguish the violation more easily.

#### Nullable Example

`For the versions of Dart before 2.12`, your typical example should be look like this:

```dart
import 'package:meta/meta.dart';

class Product {
  final int id;
  final String name;
  final int price;
  final String size;
  final String image;
  final int weight;

  const Product({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.name,
    @required this.price,
    this.size,
    this.image,
    this.weight,
  }) : assert(id != null && name != null && price != null);
}
```

Comment: now checking what this assert is for (or was in the past).... I would like to mention thath In latest update there is "null-safety" feature.

Comment: and thanks for updating. In production it is ignored, for me it looked like some validations. Is there some alternative for production code ?

Comment: @sonic you can expect `assertion` as pre-test. For production you should check `crashlytics` or `sentry.io`.

Comment: @EsenMehmet I understand that asserts works in debug mode and we use them to check parameters and variables' value. The question is when I check a variable with assert in debug mode and it gives me an error if the value doesn't meet the assert's condition, Who will check that in production mode if user enters a wrong value in the input? So my app will crash then? I can't figure out this.

Comment: @Patzu for `user input`, you shouldn't use `assert`. It's about state management which is pretty extensive and subjective topic. If user input logic throws an error, use `try/catch` and depend on the error, manage the state accordingly. Otherwise you can just create `String?` variable that indicates error message, that is null if no error is exists. As I said, it's very subjective and there are many many ways to achieve that.

Comment: It must be noted that if you want to use assert then you have to enable it while execution as it can only be used in the development mode and not in productive mode. If it is not enabled then it will be simply be ignored while execution.

Answer (score 21):

From [here](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert):

> During development, use an assert statement — assert(condition, optionalMessage); — to disrupt normal execution if a boolean condition is false.

Suppose you want to open a URL that must begin with `"https"`. How will you confirm this? Here's an example.

Example:

```
void openUrl({String url}) {
  assert(url.startsWith('https'), 'The url should start with https');
  
  // We can proceed as we 'https' in the url.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

An **assert** is similar to an **Error** in that it is for reporting bad states that should never happen. The difference is that **asserts** are only checked in debug mode. They are completely **ignored** in **production mode**.

Ex:

```
OverlayEntry({
  @required this.builder,
  bool opaque = false,
  bool maintainState = false,
}) : assert(builder != null),
      assert(opaque != null),
      assert(maintainState != null),
      _opaque = opaque,
      _maintainState = maintainState;
```

Answer (score 1):

https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#assert
During development, use an assert statement — assert(condition, optionalMessage); — to disrupt normal execution if a boolean condition is false. You can find examples of assert statements throughout this tour. Here are some more:

// Make sure the variable has a non-null value.
assert(text != null);

// Make sure the value is less than 100.
assert(number < 100);

// Make sure this is an https URL.
assert(urlString.startsWith('https'));
To attach a message to an assertion, add a string as the second argument to assert (optionally with a trailing comma):

assert(urlString.startsWith('https'),
'URL ($urlString) should start with "https".');
The first argument to assert can be any expression that resolves to a boolean value. If the expression’s value is true, the assertion succeeds and execution continues. If it’s false, the assertion fails and an exception (an AssertionError) is thrown.

When exactly do assertions work? That depends on the tools and framework you’re using:

Flutter enables assertions in debug mode.
Development-only tools such as dartdevc typically enable assertions by default.
Some tools, such as dart run and dart2js support assertions through a command-line flag: --enable-asserts.
In production code, assertions are ignored, and the arguments to assert aren’t evaluated.

Answer (score 1):

As a programmer, it is very necessary to make an errorless code, and finding errors is very difficult and time taking. Dart provides a solution in the form of `assert` to validate your code and to make sure the code will work fine without any error. The `assert` is useful in debugging and it uses a boolean condition in its syntax. If the boolean expression in assert statement is true then the code continues to execute, but if it returns false then the code ends with Assertion Error.

Answer (score 0):

The assert statement is a useful tool to debug the code and it uses boolean conditions for testing. It is very necessary to make an errorless code is very necessary and finding the error is very difficult in a big program. Dart provides the assert statements to check the error.

```
Syntax: assert(condition);
```

Make sure the str has a non-null value.

`assert(str != null);`

Make sure the num is less than 50.

`assert(num < 50);`
`

Answer (score -1):

An **assert** is similar to an **Error** in that it is for reporting bad states that should never happen. The difference is that **asserts** are only checked in debug mode. They are completely ignored in production mode.